# How to add QueryHints on Default Spring Data JPA Methods?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am able to use Query Cache with Spring Data JPA for my custom query methods like below.

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, String> {
@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value ="true") })
Country findByCountryName(String countryName);
@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value ="true") })
Country findByCountryCode(String countryCode); }
```

However, how to add @QueryHints on existing parent methods like findAll()?

Thanks.

Comment: @oliver-gierke, do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to override them and add the @QueryHint annotations, but they are ignored.

Comment: @user791694, see sgp15's answer at below http://stackoverflow.com/a/10876707/418439

Answer (score 6, accepted):

findAll(), findOne() etc. are not Query(s). Any caching specifications on the entity take effect in these methods.

For example,

```
@Cacheable
@Entity
public class User {

}
```

Comment: I have these set and the for findAll it goes to database. Is there anything I need to turn on ?

Comment: @ Cacheable doesn't seem to have any effect on findAll(). My understanding is that findOne() is linked to the "Level 2 cache" but findAll() linked to the "Query cache". To cache the findAll(), i've override the method and add the @ queryhints.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, there was no support for query hint annotations in default CRUD methods, but apparently it hass been fixed for version 1.6M1:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-173