# Caching of default Spring Data JPA Methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-data-jpa

Task: make basic methods of spring jpa data cacheable (using hibernate/jpa), like

```
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)
List<T> findAll();
etc
```

and do it on some kind of top generic interface level, without custom dao implementations.

This is continuation of original topic
[How to add QueryHints on Default Spring Data JPA Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371311/how-to-add-queryhints-on-default-spring-data-jpa-methods)

I haven't still found the solution, but tried to solve it with different ways, including adding annotations like 
`@javax.persistence.Cacheable` and `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache` 
on data model class.

---

Here are some excerpts of my config:

1. pom.xml (taken from [here](http://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/hibernate-4-and-ehcache-higher-than-2-4-3/)):

   ```
   ...
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
               <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
       <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ...
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ...
   ```
2. applicationContext.xml:

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
   </bean>     
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   </bean>
   ```
3. persistence.xml:

   ```
   ...
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
   <properties>
       ...
       <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
       <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
   </properties>
   ...
   ```
4. Apart from all above I have configured spring 3.2 cache, but eventually I want to have a solution not based on spring cache, so at the moment I don't use spring cache config.
5. My model looks like:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ABC")
   @Cacheable(true)
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
   public class ABC {
   ...
   ```
6. My parent generic DAO looks like:

   ```
   public interface CacheableGenericDao<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
       List<T> findAll();
       Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
       <S extends T> S save(S entity);
       ...
   ```

---

P.S. Here is one more useful [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/106093-query-caching) concerning the topic, but I do want use basic method names.

So what am I missing conceptually? Is there any approach at all or do I want too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how the things seem to go: [jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-173](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-173)